# Regular expression not working (cannot convert string to int (Regex.IsMatch)

Tags: c#, .net, regex

There is a really simple answer to this, I know there is. But I cannot get my head around it.
Its a console application you enter a word "password" and it will tell me whether it matches my regular expression, as you can properly gather.

Basically I want to know why this wont work:

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
    Regex regularExpression = new Regex("/^[a-z0-9_-]{3,16}$/");

    Console.Write("Enter password: ");
    string password = Console.ReadLine();

    if (Regex.IsMatch(password, regularExpression))
        Console.WriteLine("Input matches regular expression");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Input DOES NOT match regular expression");

    Console.ReadKey(); 
}
```

I'm sure it's something to do with the `Regex.IsMatch` method not being able to convert string to int.

Comment: **this code doesn't even compile** - Please address that problem and/or post the compiler error.

Answer (score 2):

Because you are using the static method `isMatch` and are giving a regex object, where it expects a regex as string, see the [Regex class](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.regex.aspx).

And additionally you don't need regex delimiters in .net.

Use this:

```
static void Main(string[] args) {
    Regex regularExpression = new Regex(@"^[a-z0-9_-]{3,16}$");

    Console.Write("Enter password: ");
    string password = Console.ReadLine();

    if (regularExpression.IsMatch(password))
        Console.WriteLine("Input matches regular expression");
    else
        Console.WriteLine("Input DOES NOT match regular expression");
    Console.ReadKey(); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Regex regularExpression = new Regex("/^[a-z0-9_-]{3,16}$/");
```

`/` is symbol, replace them to string empty => `@"^[a-z0-9_-]{3,16}$"`